# Delete child record if a field of parent is updated using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, delete

My code is:

```
    trigger ClassCustomStatus on Class__c (before update) {
        Set<Id> classSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(Class__c c : Trigger.new){
            if(c.Custom_Status__c == 'Reset'){
                classSet.add(c.Id);
            }
        }
        list<student__C> s = [SELECT id FROM Student__c WHERE class__c IN:classSet];
        Delete s;
    }
```

Here I am getting one exception this:
[image]

How can delete child records which are from **student__c**
And
How can I update a field of parent which is **Class__c**
Please help

Comment: Is `NumberOfStudents` a Roll-Up Summary Field from Students to Class?

Comment: @DavidReed  Yes this is roll-up summary field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `after update` to make sure that the record isn't already pending any changes. The rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks it's working
What should i do to update the mycount field to Zero in class__c

Comment: @gopal That should be in the `before` trigger. You can do something like `if(Trigger.isBefore) setClassToZero(Trigger.new) else deleteChildRecords(Trigger.new)` to keep everything in one trigger.

Comment: I have added another image please review

Comment: You don't manually set the value of a Roll-up Summary Field. The system will recalculate it for you. Please don't post code as images; use the `{}` tool in the editor to format code.

Comment: that's not a roll-up field that's number field

Comment: Okay I will remember this new time to post a problem with { }

Comment: @gopal So, it looks like a rollup summary field. If it were not, you would not get this compile error.

Comment: My mistake, that was another field. But thank you so much for your kind help @sfdcfox and Issue is resolved